# Positioning a div at the bottom of the page

Tags: css

I've a page I'm working on at http://s361608839.websitehome.co.uk/testsite/

Basically the div #footer should be at the bottom of the page as it comes at the end of the markup and it is also outside of #wrapper.

**HTML :**

```
 <div id="footer">This footer text should be underneath the white box (at the bottom)</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#footer{
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
color: #FFF;
}
```

I tried adding a `clear:both` to the CSS as I thought that maybe a float somewhere in the page was causing this but it didn't seem to do anything.

Any help appreciated as what it could be.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your #header position to relative and remove the 'top' declaration on #register and all is well again!

Absolute positioning wreaks havoc on page flow so keep that in mind when you use it!